# How to Mock ObjectMapper readValue method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock MAPPER.readValue() but cant get the expected output.

```
private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
PartyDetailInfo partyInfo = MAPPER.readValue(res, PartyDetailInfo.class);

        if (partyInfo.getXpartyInfo() == null || partyInfo.getXpartyInfo().getXpartyInfoItem() == null
                || partyInfo.getXpartyInfo().getXpartyInfoItem().get(0).getOrigSystemRefs() == null
                || partyInfo.getXpartyInfo().getXpartyInfoItem().get(0).getOrigSystemRefs().getOrigSystemRefsItems()
                        .isEmpty()) {
            BusinessException exception = new BusinessException(Constants.ERROR_PARTY_ID_NOT_EXIST
                    .replace(Constants.TEMP_ZERO_REPLACE_STRING, partyDetailRequest.getPartyId()));
            exception.setErrorCode(Integer.toString(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND));
            throw exception;
        }
```

I tried mocking it but i ge partyInfo = null;

```
Mockito.when(Mapper.readValue(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.eq(PartyDetailInfo.class))).thenReturn(getPartyInfoDummy());
```

Here's the getPartyInfoDummy():

```
private PartyDetailInfo getPartyInfoDummy(){
    List<XpartyInfoItem> xpartyInfoItems = new ArrayList<XpartyInfoItem>();

    XpartyInfoItem infoItem = new XpartyInfoItem();
    OrigSystemRefs origSystemRefs = new OrigSystemRefs();
    OrigSystemRefsItem origSystemRefsItem = new OrigSystemRefsItem();
    List<OrigSystemRefsItem> origSystemRefsItems = new ArrayList<OrigSystemRefsItem>();
    origSystemRefsItem.setOrigSystem("PSFT");
    origSystemRefsItem.setOrigSystemReference("PS-47439934");
    PrimaryMlsSet primaryMlsSet = new PrimaryMlsSet();
    primaryMlsSet.setNil("true");
    origSystemRefsItem.setPrimaryMlsSet(primaryMlsSet );
    origSystemRefsItems.add(origSystemRefsItem);
    origSystemRefs.setOrigSystemRefsItems(origSystemRefsItems );
    infoItem.setOrigSystemRefs(origSystemRefs);

    xpartyInfoItems.add(infoItem);
    PartyDetailInfo partyInfo = new PartyDetailInfo();
    XpartyInfo xpartyInfo = new XpartyInfo();

    xpartyInfo.setxReturnStatus(null);
    xpartyInfo.setxErrMsgs(null);
    xpartyInfo.setXpartyInfoItem(xpartyInfoItems);

    partyInfo.setXpartyInfo(xpartyInfo);

    return partyInfo;
}
```

I dont understand whats going wrong here? Need help.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `Mockito.when(Mapper.readValue` 
please make sure that the mapper is a mocked object, and the mocked mapper is set to the instance you are trying to test.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your Mapper is a locally created object and secondly it is static and final. You cannot mock such objects using mockito. Use Powermock.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of problem you may also try to use `Mockito.doReturn(...).when(...)`, when I had similiar issues it helped.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on a similar case:

```
        doThrow(IOException.class).when(objectMapper).readValue(any(A_Random_Class.class), any(Class.class));
```

This is the method I tried to mock:

```
public <T> T readValue(File src, JavaType valueType) throws IOException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException {
```